# Appending a list to another list while checking for duplicates

Tags: python, list, duplicates, append

I need some help adding a list to another list while checking for duplicates. I only want to add items to my base list that are not already there.

I cannot do this using sets because the items in the base list are also lists.

An example of my base list is as follows:

```
toCrawl=[["http://website.html",0]["http://websiteAlt.html",1]["http://websiteAlt.html",1]]
```

The list that I want to add to this is as follows:

```
newLinks=["http://websiteAlt.html","http://websiteExample.html","http://websiteExampleAlt.html"]
```

So I want to add the 'newLinks' list to the base 'toCrawl' list, however I only want to add it if the item in newLinks is not already in toCrawl.

As well as this I also want to add the items from 'newLinks' to the 'toCrawl' list as a list. So rather than adding the item in 'newLinks' as: `"http://websiteExample.html"` I want to add it to the list as a list for example: `["http://websiteExample.html",0]`

Comment: Can't you just use a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice solution would be to use list comprehension and cast your list as a set:

```
toCrawl=[["http://website.html",0],["http://websiteAlt.html",1],["http://websiteAlt.html",1]]
newLinks = set([item[0] for item in toCrawl])
print(newLinks)
```

**Output**

```
{'http://website.html', 'http://websiteAlt.html'}
```

Note that in order to remove duplicates, sets seems to be the good pratice, this is from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.
>   Common uses include membership testing, removing duplicates from a
>   sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection,
>   union, difference, and symmetric difference. (For other containers see
>   the built-in dict, list, and tuple classes, and the collections
>   module.)

Answer (score 1):

Could this be done with a dictionary instead of a list?

```
toCrawlDict = dict(toCrawl)
for link in newLinks:
    if link not in toCrawlDict:
         toCrawlDict[link] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary was a good shout thanks. I ended up going with this method however:

```
for link in newLinks:   #check every link in 'newLinks'
            if link not in toCrawl: #if the link is not in 'toCrawl'...
                toCrawl.append([link,depthFound+1]) #add the link to 'toCrawl' with the 'depthFound'
```